# Where does the GeoServer KML Reflector get its LookAt value?

Tags: geoserver, kml

I've had a lot of success pulling a KML Network Link from GeoServer 2.19.x and 2.20.x using the [KML Reflector](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/googleearth/features/kmlreflector.html), but one common user annoyance has been the bogus `LookAt` value populated at the top level of the KML GeoServer produces that send the user to the other side of the globe when it's first opened.

Here's the relevant content of the KML produced by GeoServer's KML Reflector:

```
<Folder>
    <name>MyLayer:Lines</name>
    <LookAt>
        <longitude>89.08339404914683</longitude>
        <latitude>23.59009355430345</latitude>
        <altitude>13034631.69356779</altitude>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <tilt>0</tilt>
        <range>10532666.09660703</range>
    </LookAt>
    <Placemark id="Lines.123_00349">
        <name>Lines.123_00349</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-111.1018090807534</longitude>
            <latitude>45.61957749215038</latitude>
            <altitude>51077.14333522315</altitude>
            <heading>0</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>41273.01089634309</range>
        </LookAt>
        ...
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Notice how the folder's `LookAt` value is way over in India (which is way off), while the actual Placemark's `LookAt` value is in Montana (which is correct).

I thought the folder's `LookAt` value might be based on the layer's bbox, but the value in the KML isn't even inside the bbox as I defined it in the GeoServer interface (North America, basically):
[image]

So where is the KML Reflector getting its `LookAt` value, and how do I override/change it?

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: I'd start here - https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/4fd02bd258340b1da0bcfd290cfda0f65e3a483a/src/kml/src/main/java/org/geoserver/kml/decorator/LookAtDecoratorFactory.java#L89

Comment: @IanTurton That's where I looked and although my Java is rusty, everything I saw seemed to indicate that it should be defaulting to the midpoint of the min/max, which should be getting set by the crs bounds. That's not what I'm observing.

Comment: might be a bug, I've never used the KML reflector and I don't know anyone who does